# NSInternalInconsistencyException when trying to list files in Firebase storage bucket

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get a list of all of the objects in my firebase storage bucket using the following code:

```
[listingReference listWithMaxResults:1000 completion:^(FIRStorageListResult * _Nonnull result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Error listing files");
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        } else {
            NSArray<FIRStorageReference *> *entries = result.prefixes;
            NSArray<FIRStorageReference *> *entryItems = result.items;
            NSLog(@"List folder complete");
            NSLog(@"%@", entries);
            NSLog(@"%@", entryItems);
        }
    }];
```

However, when I run the code I get the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expected gs://bucketname1/ to be a child element of gs://bucketname1/testfile

I have checked my `listingReference` by printing out the file path and it outputs `gs://bucketname1/` which I think is correct because I want to list all files in the bucket. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me like you can't actually query all of the files in a bucket so I created a folder inside of the bucket and saved my files in this folder and they could be queried there.